# check unittest.mock call arguments agnostically w.r.t. whether they have been passed as positional arguments or keyword arguments

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest.mock

When a `unittest.mock.Mock` object has been called, I can check for the argument values with the exact signature of the call:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock

m = Mock()  # creation of mock
m('foo', bar='baz')  # call to the mock
m.assert_called_once_with('foo', bar='baz')  # check call arguments
```

Checking for a different signature with the same values will fail. E.g., if we check with `'baz'` as a positional argument instead of a named argument, the assertion will fail:

```
m.assert_called_once_with('foo', 'baz')
# AssertionError: Expected call: mock('foo', 'baz')
# Actual call: mock('foo', bar='baz')
```

It has to. If the function replaced by `m` was

```
def actual_fu(foo, bar):
    # do something
```

then the calls would be equivalent, but if it was

```
def a_different_actual_fu(foo, *args, bar='some default'):
    # do something
```

then the calls would not be equivalent. `Mock` doesn't know the actual function's signature, so it can't rely on the equivalence we would have in the first case.

Is there a way of checking the call argument values that is **agnostic about whether they were passed positionally or as keyword arguments**, by letting the Mock (or an assertion helper function or similar) know about the actual function replaced by the mock?

The `Mock` object can be made aware of the object it replaces (which can be a function or method) with the optional [`spec` argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock) or with [autospeccing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#auto-speccing), but those serve a different purpose (limiting what calls to allow on the mock) and don't affect after-the-fact checking.

Comment: AFAIK Is not possible to do it in mock 1.3. But... IMHO it is not a mock duty try to understand the call semantic but just recording how you do the call. `assert_called_once_with(...)` is just what the method say and not `assert_called_with_something_that_is_equivalent_to(...)`: it sounds like more a stub's duty instead. Anyway maybe can be very useful in some cases.... I meet something that is related to this one some days ago http://stackoverflow.com/a/34811786/4101725

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The Mock object can be made aware of the object it replaces (which can be a function or method) with the optional spec argument or with `autospeccing`, but those serve a different purpose..

This is exactly what [Issue 17015: mock could be smarter and inspect the spec's signature](https://bugs.python.org/issue17015) improvement issue was about. The `spec` actually is very much related and now makes the mock function-signature-aware.

See how mock fails when we assert mock was called with a keyword argument  - without letting it know about the actual function signature:

```
>>> from unittest.mock import Mock
>>>
>>> def actual_fu(foo, bar):
...     pass
>>>
>>> m = Mock()
>>> m('foo', bar='baz')
<Mock name='mock()' id='4356741496'>
>>>
>>> m.assert_called_once_with(foo='foo', bar='baz')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/unittest/mock.py", line 803, in assert_called_once_with
    return self.assert_called_with(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/unittest/mock.py", line 792, in assert_called_with
    raise AssertionError(_error_message()) from cause
AssertionError: Expected call: mock(bar='baz', foo='foo')
Actual call: mock('foo', bar='baz')
```

And now, see how it all passes if we provide a `spec`:

```
>>> m = Mock(spec=actual_fu)
>>> m('foo', bar='baz')
<Mock name='mock()' id='4356249528'>
>>> 
>>> m.assert_called_once_with(foo='foo', bar='baz')
>>> m.assert_called_once_with('foo', bar='baz')
>>> m.assert_called_once_with(bar='baz', foo='foo')
>>> m.assert_called_once_with('foo', 'baz')
>>>
```

(Used Python 3.5.1)

Comment: Oh, wow. I had actually tried something like that, but probably with Python 3.2 where it didn't work. Re-tried with Python 3.4 just now and it works! :-)