# Extract unittest.mock call arguments agnostically w.r.t whether they have been passes as positional arguments or keyword arguments

Tags: python, python-unittest, method-call, python-unittest.mock

This question is similar to [check unittest.mock call arguments agnostically w.r.t. whether they have been passed as positional arguments or keyword arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945206/check-unittest-mock-call-arguments-agnostically-w-r-t-whether-they-have-been-pa), but with an extension.

Given a mocked function with a given `spec`, it is possible to check whether a function was called with the right arguments, regardless of whether the function was called with positional arguments or keyword arguments (or a mixture of both). So obviously, `mock` knows how to translate between those two.

My problem is a little more complicated, because given this signature:

```
def myfun(a, b, some_list, c=3, d=4)
    # Do something with a, b, c, d and some_list
    return None
```

all the following calls should be regarded as correct:

```
myfun(b=2, a=1, some_list = [3, 4, 5])
myfun(1, 2, [5, 4, 3])
myfun(1, 2, d=4, some_list=[4, 3, 5])
```

The values for `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` should be `1`, `2`, `3` and `4` respectively, but the value for `some_list` should just contain the values `[3, 4, 5]`, without regard to order.

What I would like to do in a unittest is something like this (when `complicated_fun` should at one point call `myfun` with the given arguments):

```
def test_complicated_fun(self):
    myobject = MyClass(...)
    myobject.myfun = Mock(return_value = None, spec=myobject.myfun)
    myobject.complicated_fun()

    myobject.myfun.assert_called_once()
    self.assertEqual(myobject.myfun.call_args['a'], 1)
    self.assertEqual(myobject.myfun.call_args['b'], 2)
    self.assertEqual(myobject.myfun.call_args['c'], 3)
    self.assertEqual(myobject.myfun.call_args['d'], 4)
    self.assertCountEqual(myobject.myfun.call_args['mylist'], [3, 4, 5])
```

Except this will of course fail, seeing as we can't subscript `call_args`.

Is there a way around this, and to get the value of `mylist` directly from the mock?
I could make a workaround it by using `myobject.myfun.call_args[1].get('mylist', myobject.myfun.call_args[0][2])`.

But that:

- Depends on manually specifying again that `mylist` is the argument at index 2, meaning if my spec changes I should also manually edit the test.
- Doesn't feel very pythonic

Comment: Note that in your example, all parameters are positional arguments, judging by the second call, but in this case the third call will not work. Also, you probably know that using a list as a default argument is not a good idea.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I fixed some mistakes, but I'm not using a list as default argument. Where the list is specified, it's just in a call; `some_list` doesn't have a default value.

Comment: Ah, sorry, got that one wrong. Now the example is more clear, thanks. I don't think there is an easy way to achieve what you want to do, but I will have another look later.